# Como contar o total de registros em uma query com limit e offset?

Tags: laravel

Em uma *query* com *paginate* eu usaria o `total()` na *view* para retornar o total de registros.

Usando o *limit* e *offset* não é possível fazer isso, existe alguma alternativa que não envolva fazer uma nova *query* somente para contar?

```
$comentarios = $this->comentario::with('user')
    ->where('serie_id', $request->get('serie_id'))
    ->orderBy('created_at', $filtro)
    ->limit(2)
    ->offset($offset)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu creio que dá pra fazer o que você quer separando as queries e reutilizando:

```
$query = $this->comentario()
              ->with('user')
              ->where('serie_id', $request->get('serie_id'));

$quantidade_comentarios = $query->count();

$comentarios $query->orderBy('created_at', $filtro)
       ->limit(2)
       ->offset($offset)
       ->get();
```

**Nota**: No caso acima, duas queries serão executadas, porém reutilizando trechos da Query Builder do Laravel.

Comment: Ou seja, ele utiliza o builder mas, no final das contas são 2 SQL

Comment: Sim, não tem como fazer de outro jeito. Até o Paginator internamente faz isso.

Comment: Sim, não tem como mesmo, foi o que eu expliquei na minha resposta, a sua resposta dá a entender que nao são duas SQL e pode confundir.

Answer (score 2):

Quando é utilizadoo `limit` e o `offset` é obrigatório o uso de uma outra `SQL` para contar a quantidade de registros. Pra mim nesse caso pode utilizar o `paginate()` que vai ter o mesmo efeito e além do mais traz o total de registro, um exemplo disso é o `JSON` gerado, observe:

```
{
   "total": 50,
   "per_page": 15,
   "current_page": 1,
   "last_page": 4,
   "first_page_url": "http://laravel.app?page=1",
   "last_page_url": "http://laravel.app?page=4",
   "next_page_url": "http://laravel.app?page=2",
   "prev_page_url": null,
   "path": "http://laravel.app",
   "from": 1,
   "to": 15,
   "data":[
        {
            // Result Object
        },
        {
            // Result Object
        }
   ]
}
```

nesse exemplo tem um chave com o nome de total, que é a quantidade de registro contidos na sua base de dados, vale lembrar que qualquer filtro colocado também reflete nessa chave trazendo então os dados contido mediante o filtro, mas também internamente são executadas duas instruções `SQL`.

Então, só pra ratificar se for utilizar `limit` e `offset` e quiser a quantidade de registro dessa tabela deve fazer outra `SQL` para obter tal informação e isso não vai acarretar mau desempenho, isso somente não, mas, outros fatores em conjunto podem.

No seu código:

```
$comentarios = $this->comentario::with('user')
    ->where('serie_id', $request->get('serie_id'))
    ->orderBy('created_at', $filtro)
    ->paginate(2);
```

---

No código se quiser passar os parametros é só seguir o que está no [framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/Paginator.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Pagination/Paginator.php)

```
paginate(int $perPage = null, 
         array $columns = ['*'], 
         string $pageName = 'page', 
         int|null $page = null)
```

que terá o mesmo efeito (com duas SQL isso não tem por onde escapar).

<sub>Referencia: [Converting Results To JSON](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination#converting-results-to-json)</sub>